# Web Scraping returns empty values

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, tweepy

I'm new to Python. I trying to run a web scraping app. 
When I run the below python scripts, I am getting empty values. Please advice.

```
import bs4
import requests
url2= 'https://bitcoinfees.info/'
res2= requests.get(url)
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text,'html.parser')
highfee= soup2.select_one('html.wf-roboto-n5-active.wf-roboto-n4-        active.wf-active body div.container ul.list-group li.list-group-item  span.badge').text
print(highfee)
```

Comment: What do you expect your script will do when you yourself can't clarify what you wanna achieve? Please, edit you post to make it specific.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors in your example. `requests.get(url)` should be `(url2)` and then `highfee` has a bunch of stuff in there.  It seems like you are just looking for the first `span`.  In this case you can do `soup2.select_one('span').text`  So, all together you have

```
url2= 'https://bitcoinfees.info/'
res2= requests.get(url2)
soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text,'html.parser')
highfee= soup2.select_one('span').text
print(highfee)
```

if it is a different span you are looking for you can use `soup2.find()` in this case, you are looking for the tag `<span class="badge">` You can search these by using

```
soup2.find("span", class_="badge").string
```

see the [soup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for searching by css class